# Referencing next and previous row values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was recently investigating an issue where a percentage of rows written to a certain dbs table had null values in a column that should not be null. When ordering that table by its timestamp column, I noticed that the rows with null values weren't scattered about randomly, but came in large chunks. There were thousands of rows with that column null, followed by thousands of rows with a valid value, and so on in large bands like this.

I wanted to investigate what was happening at the borders of these bands, where the column switched from null to non-null and vice versa. Finding a pattern in the times or data surrounding these switches seemed very useful in debugging the problem.

I couldn't think of a way to have sql select only these rows, so I ended up writing a quick program to process the data and return what I wanted. See the pseudo code below to demonstrate the algorithm.

```
resultSet = db.query("select * from table t order by t.timestamp")
prevRow = null
// for simplicity, let's assume there's always at least 2 rows
currentRow = resultSet.next()
nextRow = resultSet.next()

while(resultSet.hasNext()) 

    // if the null state of column we care about has changed around this current row
    if(hasNullColumn(prevRow) != hasNullColumn(nextRow)) printRow(currentRow)   

    prevRow = currentRow;
    currentRow = nextRow; 
    nextRow = resultSet.next();
```

But I was left really curious whether there was a way to write a sql query that will return only the rows printed by the above logic? Is that possible?

Comment: There are `LAG` and `LEAD` functions, which I believe are part of the ANSI standard for SQL.  SQL Server supports those functions starting with SQL Server 2012.  Not sure about MySQL though (you tagged both).

Comment: Is this question about MySQL or SQL-Server? They're not the same thing, please pick one tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a unique id column and to make things interesting that it doesn't track the increases in timestamp column. Also assume that there are no timestamps that are equal.

```
select pt.* from
(Select max(ptime) as prevtime,min(ntime) as nextime from
((Select timestamp as ptime) as prev,
(Select timestamp as ntime) as next
where prev.ptime < next.ntime and prev.id<>next.id) as s1 group by ptime, ntime) as pn
inner join 
t as pt on pn.prevtime=pt.timestamp inner join 
t as nt on pn.nexttime=nt.timestamp
where pt.ncol!=nt.ncol;
```

Explanation: s1 provides pairs of times that are before and after each other. pn groups them to get a list of all adjacent pairs of times. pt provides the rest of the columns for the previous time in pn, and nt provides the rest of the columns for the next time. When the column which I named ncol switches values the prior row gets spit out into the resultset. If there are multiple nonnull values and it was only interesting to find the switches between null and non-null, then change pt.ncol!=nt.ncol to isnull(pt.ncol)!=isnull(nt.ncol).