# MySql: Get next row values

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the sample dataset from the table:

```
|  callid    |   called     |   calling   |        end          | 
|------------|--------------|-------------|---------------------|
| 1411482360 | 001143792042 | 08444599175 | 2014-07-31 13:55:03 |
| 1476992122 | 001143792042 | 08441713191 | 2014-07-31 14:05:10 |
```

So far I've managed to get previous row values and I need the next row values also. Here's my query:

```
SELECT c.called as customer, c.calling as company, DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d') as _date,
        @G := if(@prevComp <> c.calling AND @prevCust = c.called AND @prevDate = DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d'), 1, 0) as Gain,
        @prevCust := c.called as prevCust,
        @prevComp := c.calling as prevComp,
        @prevDate := DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d') as prevDate
FROM cdrdata_archive c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prevComp := NULL, @prevCust := NULL, @prevDate := NULL) prevVals
ORDER BY c.called, c.`end`
```

The above query returns the following result set:

```
Customer     Company      Date        prevCust     prevComp     prevDate     Gain

00140443360  08434599117  2014-01-28  00140443360  08434599117  2014-01-28   0
00475172558  08434599218  2014-01-27  00475172558  08434599218  2014-01-27   0
00475172558  08434593455  2014-01-27  00475172558  08434599118  2014-01-27   1
```

I need the previous and next row values to calculate the lost and gained calls to every company. I managed to get correct gained values, however to compute the `Lost` values (similar to `Gain` but in a new column), **I need the next customer, company and date**.

Can this be fitted into this query without much cost or do I need to rewrite it ?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160298/referencing-next-and-previous-row-values help?

Answer (score 0):

research using MySQL `LIMIT` clause. Your rows are returned with an `ORDER BY` so you do have an order but you do not have a 'number in the list' , which LIMIT  is

So you have your query - and at the end of the SQL you append

`LIMIT $x, 1` where you have `LIMIT <offset>, <count>` So your count is your row (1) and every time you goto the 'next' row you change

```
$x = $x + 1
```

Hope this helps.
 http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

So for your **third** query of the type you showed would be:

```
SELECT c.called as customer, c.calling as company, DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d') as _date,
        @G := if(@prevComp <> c.calling AND @prevCust = c.called AND @prevDate = DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d'), 1, 0) as Gain,
        @prevCust := c.called as prevCust,
        @prevComp := c.calling as prevComp,
        @prevDate := DATE_FORMAT(c.`end`,'%Y-%m-%d') as prevDate
FROM cdrdata_archive c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prevComp := NULL, @prevCust := NULL, @prevDate := NULL) prevVals
ORDER BY c.called, c.`end` LIMIT 2,1
```